# ExtJs Vs Ext GWT Vs SmartGWT

Tags: javascript, extjs, smartgwt, gwt-ext

I am going to start a new application which mainly consist NavigationPane, Grid, Toolbar. Layout should look like this demo page http://www.gwt-ext.com/demo/

I am quite confused which one to use in terms of writing less code, more performant, etc..
Could someone tell the pros and cons of all these technologies.

All the while I coded in javascript, so that way ExtJs seems to be the easy one for me to code. But I am curios to try GWT Ext, Is it true that it could do a lot just by writing few lines of java code.

For eg: To achieve the layout ( given in  above gwt ext demo url), which one should I opt ExtJs  or GWT Ext.

I read SmartGWT is relatively slower than GwtEXT. Does it have any advantage over GWT EXT. I am also looking for hibernate based data modules ( as my application is going to have many database calls). Anyone of SmartGWT or GWTExt has support for such modules. I came to know that smartgwt doesn't offer all of smartclient enterprise version functionalities, that we are allowed only a few of smartclient features. Will it be an issue?

Your response is highly appreciated.

Comment: You reference GWT Ext.  Note that this is different from Ext GWT.  One of the two is better than the other - I can never remember which one.

Comment: see this thread : http://extjs.com/forum/showthread.php?t=33091

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To write the least code, use SmartGWT Pro.  It provides a wizard that allows you to just pick from a list of Hibernate entities you've created, and instantly you have the ability to perform all CRUD operations on that entity, no code required.  Then you can add business logic.

The wizard:

http://www.smartclient.com/smartgwtee/showcase/#tools_hibernate_wizard

The link about is just screenshots, but there are several Hibernate samples in the showcase.  See especially the Master-Detail Batch Load and Save sample.

As far as performance, real-world performance of most enterprise apps is dictated by how often the application has to contact the server.  In this area SmartGWT has a large lead because of features like Adaptive Filtering (see the Featured area in the SmartGWT showcase).

Almost all reports we receive of SmartGWT being "slow" are due to having Firebug enabled.  Disable Firebug and performance is fine, so normal end users will never perceive slowness.

Comment: We've made this even better now - you don't have to use a wizard, you can just declare what Hibernate entity (or any other POJO) should be used to configure components, and forms, grids, etc will be generated on the fly.  The new QuickStart Guide (http://blog.isomorphic.com/?p=227) explains in detail.

Answer (score 7):

The GWT-Ext main page now says

"GWT-Ext is no longer under active development and has been superseded by Smart GWT. Assistance will be provided to existing users of GWT-Ext looking to migrate to Smart GWT."

so why would anyone use it?

Answer (score 3):

About 6 months ago, we studied whether we would use ExtJS or GWT-Ext for an internal application. We wanted the back-end to be J2EE standard frameworks (struts, spring, hibernate for persistence, etc.). We ended up choosing ExtJS because it seemed to us that GWT was not stable enough (too many changes in the API that is still recent), and Ext-GWT was always lagging behind in development.

Comment: We did a similar choice, we ended up using only gwt,without any wrapper-libraries. Has worked out pretty well for us.

Answer (score 1):

> application which mainly consist NavigationPane, Grid, Toolbar.

Well, this tells us a **lot** about your app, doesn't it :)

I think it comes down to how good you are at either Java or JavaScript. They are quite a different languages you know :) But if you are well-versed at both but only used Ext JS, then picking up Ext GWT (or GWT Ext, if you meant that), shouldn't be such a great deal. And if that application you are planning is going to be as simple and small as your description of it, then it's probably a perfect opportunity to try out something new.

Answer (score 1):

I use GWT-Ext and it is quite good especially if you don't mind tweaking things with JSNI to customize the already existing Ext widgets it is incredibly powerful. Unfortunately development is stagnant, so my future projects will probably be either in SmartGWT or Ext-GWT. SmartGWT is written by Sanjiv Jivan (same guy who wrote GWT-Ext) and it has most of the widgets we need. I must say most of the skins are quite dated except the Enterprise skin which looks good, but you can always roll your own skin.